# Unable to create Kafka Consumer Groups simultaneously

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a 3 node Kafka cluster setup on my stage environment. I am using the same Kafka setup to create consumer groups on startup of my spring application instances. In doing so, as I have a clustered setup of application instances I am actually attempting to bring up 8-10 consumer groups(with 10 consumers each) simultaneously.

While trying to do the same as mentioned above, the issue that I have identified here is that not all of the consumer groups get created in Kafka. Always there is at-least 1 or 2 or may be more than that consumer groups are missing.

After debugging, was able to identify in Kafka internal logs that I was getting debug log which says “**Consumer Coordinator lookup Failed** …” & “**Coordinator discovery failed, refreshing metadata** …”. And these log statements would come up only for those consumer groups that have failed to start.

I would like to request you all to provide me a few suggestions with of what further can be tried to get this configuration up & running.

Also, it would be really appreciated if any inputs anyone can provide on about simultaneous creation of Kafka consumer groups & upto what extent it is possible at a point of time viz. For how many consumer groups I can request Kafka for creation simultaneously?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you run `kafka-topics` from a machine with the topic so we can see the topic, partition distribution?
`kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic <topic-name> --zookeeper <zoo_url>:2181`

Comment: Yeah sure. I have created one topic named pocTopic with 10 partitions.  Unable to add complete description of topic in comment due to restriction of number of characters

Comment: Replication factor: 3?

Comment: Replication factor is 1

Comment: Hmmm, 1. Not sure if this will help. There is an `offsets.topic.replication.factor` if it is set to 1, it should probably be 3. It was a new setting 0.11. The offsets.topic.replication.factor broker config is now enforced upon auto topic creation. Internal auto topic creation will fail with a GROUP_COORDINATOR_NOT_AVAILABLE error until the cluster size meets this replication factor requirement. The other thing is that maybe your poll in your consumer is not frequent enough, and it disconnects.

Comment: Yes, `offsets.topic.replication.factor` is currently set to 1. In my configuration, num.partitions is set to 2. And as per my knowledge, it is required that latter should be less than or equal to the former configuration parameter. Although, I'll try out both the suggestions provided by you & will let you know. Thanks Daniel!